# Dimension of space of K-fixed vectors

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups

If $G$ is an unramified group over an $p$-adic field $F$, the Satake isomorphism identifies the spherical Hecke algebra with respect to a special maximal compact subgroup $K$. In particular,

(1) $H(G(F),K)$ is commutative.

As a corollary:

(2) If ($\pi,V)$ is an irreducible admissible representation of $G(F)$ with a non-zero $K$-fixed vector, then dim $V^K=1$.

This follows by showing that it's a simple module over the Hecke algebra and then applying "Schur's lemma."

Is the condition of being special necessary to guarantee the second result? In other words, is (2) true if $K$ is an arbitrary maximal compact subgroup?

Comment: My question is whether (2) is true for an arbitrary maximal compact subgroup.

Comment: OK. I deleted my comment.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  For background, Cartier (in the Corvallis volume) proves that when K is special, there's a Satake-like isomorphism.  That gives (1) and (2).  But I've never tried to work out the structure of the Hecke algebra for a non-special maximal parahoric, e.g., in a ramified unitary group.  Someone should do that, if it hasn't been done before!  Note that H(G,K) will be a subalgebra of the Iwahori Hecke algebra when K is any parahoric, so explicit generators and relations can be used.